# Add alt and title and formatting when using PHP Glob to Display Images

Tags: php, image, title, alt

So I am using this bit of PHP to display all the images in a particular directory:

```
<?php
  $dirname = "cards/";
  $images = glob($dirname."*.png");
  foreach($images as $image) {
  echo '<img src="'.$image.'" />';
  }
?>
```

It works fine to load my images. But I am wondering how I can have it echo the html to not only load the image, but display the file name as alt and title attributes. I tried using the following but it loads up the dir name as well as the file name. Trying to just get the file name.

```
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.$image.'" title="'.$image.'" />';
```

In addition, I want to display only five images per row, is there a way of formatting that with automatically generated images?

UPDATE: In regards to displaying five images at a time, I don't want a slider or pagination. I want all images in the dir loaded, but with a line break after every 5 images.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you understand what the `alt` and `title` properties are for? Right now the code seems to imply you're just going to repeat the file name. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146115/about-the-title-alt-attributes

Comment: Title is not a valid attribute for the img tag in the Html5 spec.

Comment: Just use `basename($image)` and use a counter inside your foreach loop and echo `<br>` (or whatever you want) each 5th pass.

Comment: It **is** going to repeat the file name. That is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. That is why I want the alt and title to match the image being pulled from the dir, not generic filler that all images share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your loop to get the name of the image without the file extension

```
<div class="row">
<?php $dirname = "cards/"; $images = glob($dirname . "*.png");  ?>
<?php foreach ($images as $image)  :?>
    <?php $title = pathinfo($image); ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="<?= $image ?>" alt="<?=title['filename']?>" class="img-thumbnail" >
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

as far as displaying 5 images per row you want to create  pagination and return 5 images each time you click on the link. look for jQuery slider plugin.

Test produces the html markup below but only 4 images per row.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">                           
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="downloads/hex_bg_black.jpg" alt="hex_bg_black" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>          
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="downloads/zh_bg_1.jpg" alt="zh_bg_1" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work as intended. It generates an <img> code that looks like the following: `<img src="cards/punk20.png" alt="" title="">`

Comment: That works for specifying specific file names, I am generating a series of images using `glob`. It doesn't produce the same result. What should my php look like with your lines added in?

Comment: Thank you mdamia, works like a charm! In regards to the jQuery slider, see my updated question.

Comment: see updated answer. that should do it, I used bootstrap.