# Add a tooltip to each image using the title attribute

Tags: html, css

```
<br><img title="Cool as ninja!" src="/images/profile2.png" width="300"></br>
<br> <strong>Who's this pretty girl ninja!?</strong>
<br><img  title="Cool dude bro!" src="/images/profile5.png"></br>
<br> <strong>Incredible Hulk!</strong>
<br><img title="What's up bro, like my new car?" src ="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/VDP/9816_cc2400_001_PVG_cherokee_712x534._V291818945_.png" width="300">
<br><strong>This is a nice, fast, as well as strong car!</strong></br>
```

Code Avengers keeps saying I need to put `title` to each image. When I have already done that. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean, added 24 characters in body? I am new to HTML and CSS

Comment: What is *"It"*? May try adding an `alt` attribute instead.

Comment: @kukkuz took the time to format your code to be readable as code here. You should take a little time and explore the formatting options and taking the [tour] wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: I've tried using the "alt" attribute but it did not work

Comment: You should mention that in your post - we're not mind readers and didn't look over your shoulder while you tried a gazillion things that didn't work.

Comment: @Filburt I tried the code like this: <br><img title="What's up bro, like my new car?" src ="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/VDP/9816_cc2400_001_PVG_cherokee_712x534._V291818945_.png" width="300" alt="No image is shown"> but it keeps saying the same thing, "Add a tooltip to each image using the title attribute.

Comment: Can you explain better what you want' Put an editable code please

Comment: @TripTherapy I want to be able to put tooltip to the images, but the problem is I have already done that, but from where I am coding is codeavengers.com keep saying that I need to add tooltips to each images using the title attritubutes.

Comment: We still have no clue who or what this nagging "It" is, but since all the `img` in your sample code clearly have the required `title` attribute maybe you just missed one `img` in your actual code. If you cannot tell who/what is validating and rejecting your code, we'll not be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Filburt Sorry for the confusion, but the "it" that I keep mentioning is that the phone in Code Avengers, basically whatever you put in your code is showed on that phone.

Comment: @NeoAstro check my answer

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("img").on("mouseover",function(event){
 $(".tooltip").remove();
  Title=$(this).attr("title");
  $(this).removeAttr("title")
  let tooltip=$("<div/>",{class:"tooltip",html:Title,style:"left:"+event.pageX+"px;"+"top:"+event.pageY+"px;"});
  $(this).parent().append(tooltip);
  $(this).parent().find(".tooltip").fadeIn();
});
$("img").on("mouseleave",function(event){
 $(this).attr("title", Title)
 Title="";
 $(".tooltip").remove();
});
```

```css
.tooltip{
position: absolute;
background-color:#000;
color:#fff;
padding:5px;
display:none;
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><img title="Cool as ninja!" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSwE4cobK7ZLOS6mo2oE07NHNJLfxAcD9_NqdocEbmMWrMNj1fi" width="300"><br>
<br> <strong>Who's this pretty girl ninja!?</strong>
<br><img  title="Cool dude bro!" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRguGplqscctefh162YhLoMvnu398pKjyQ-2aJ8fFYNyunToDbB"><br>
<br> <strong>Incredible Hulk!</strong>
<br><img title="What's up bro, like my new car?" src ="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/VDP/9816_cc2400_001_PVG_cherokee_712x534._V291818945_.png" width="300">
<br><strong>This is a nice, fast, as well as strong car!</strong><br>
```

Comment: Nice example but unlikely to solve the OP's problem of getting his code submitted to Code Avengers validated.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is about the using of alt and title.

### title

The `title` attribute is a global attribute, which means that you can use it on *all* elements. In general (note that one some elements (e.g. the `abbr` element) it has a special meaning) it is defined as:

> The `title` attribute represents advisory information for the element […]

You should read the definition of the attribute, it explains how it should (not) be used.

### alt

The `alt` attribute can only be used on the `area`, `input` (for image buttons) and `img` element. For `img`, it has this meaning:

> the value of the `alt` attribute is the `img` element’s fallback content, and provides equivalent content for users and user agents who cannot process images or have image loading disabled.

There are many rules how you should (not) use this attribute.

---

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146115/about-the-title-alt-attributes)

```html
<br><img alt="Cool as ninja!" title="Cool as ninja!" src="/images/profile2.png" width="300"></br>
<br> <strong>Who's this pretty girl ninja!?</strong>
<br><img  alt="Cool dude bro!" title="Cool dude bro!" src="/images/profile5.png"></br>
<br> <strong>Incredible Hulk!</strong>
<br><img alt="What's up bro, like my new car?"  title="What's up bro, like my new car?" src ="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/VDP/9816_cc2400_001_PVG_cherokee_712x534._V291818945_.png" width="300">
<br><strong>This is a nice, fast, as well as strong car!</strong></br>
```

Comment: the phone keeps saying the same thing which is "Try again
Add a tooltip to each image using the  title attribute"

Comment: Do you mean this one? <br><img title="Cool as ninja!" src="/images/profile2.png" width="300"></br>
<br> <strong>Who's this pretty girl ninja!?</strong>
<br><img  title="Cool dude bro!" src="/images/profile5.png"></br>
<br> <strong>Incredible Hulk!</strong>
<br><img title="What's up bro, like my new car?" src ="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/VDP/9816_cc2400_001_PVG_cherokee_712x534._V291818945_.png" width="300">
<br><strong>This is a nice, fast, as well as strong car!</strong></br>

Comment: This one is the original and you have to add the tooltip by title attribute?

Comment: Yes, and I have already done the tooltip that you told me to do, as well as other people's suggestion by those solutions just seemed to not work

Comment: copy and paste this new solution, use title and alt together maybe works ^^

Comment: Ok bro this is going a little confusing, I want to show you the actual picture of what's going on, how do I send you the picture?

Comment: These solutions are not working my friend, either that or, maybe I have other codes that are also like this as well.

Comment: Nevermind, I have already answered my own question, I just had to delete some code in my code, as there was too much code. So, for all of the people who gave me solution worked as well. Thank you all.